# Proof by Mathematical Induction: The $n$-th multiple of $9$ is given by $T_n =10(n-1) + 10 -n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Observing the multiples of $9$, we see that the last digit goes on a cycle from $0$ to $9$, forward and backwards:

$$-1\mathbf{8},-\mathbf{9}, \mathbf{0}, \mathbf{9},1\mathbf{8},2\mathbf{7},3\mathbf{6},4\mathbf{5},5\mathbf{4},6\mathbf{3},7\mathbf{2},8\mathbf{1},9\mathbf{0},9\mathbf{9},10\mathbf{8}, \ldots$$

and the previous digits are always growing in $1$. So I came up with a formula to generate this table, which is like this:

$$T_n =10(n-1) + 10 -n$$

Now the question is:

> How could I make a proof by mathematical induction of this formula?

Comment: Simplifying the formula gives $T_n=10n-10+10-n=9n$. So, $T_n$ is already the $n$-th multiple of $9$. No induction needed.

Comment: The RHS of the equality can be simplified as $9n$. Do you really want to prove that $9n=9n$ by induction? If so, then what did you try?

Comment: Your „table“ us just all the numbers multiplied by nine, so your „formula“ can be greatly simplified to be $T_n = 9n$. Moreover I don’t really know what you mean with „proof of my mathematical induction of this formula$? Just solve your formula for $9n$ and you are done. Even if you mean to prove your claim on the last digits, induction does not really make sense, since induction is a tool to prove a statement *for all* $n$, and your statement cannot be easily phrased in such a way, since it relies on neighboring numbers...

Comment: What you did was scratch paper, not a proof.

Comment: Well, If you want induction:  Then $T_{n+1} = T_n + 9$ and $T_n = 10(n-1)+10 - n$ so $T_{n+1}= 10(n-1)+10-n+9= 10([n-1]+1)+9-n=10([n+1]-1)+10-n-1=10([n+1]-1)+10-[n+1]$ will do it.  ... But as others have stated $T_n =10(n-1) + 10-n + 9 = 9n$ is ....pretty basic.

Comment: Problem is.  Although it is a neat observation that if $k = 10a + b$ and if $b\ne 0$ then $k + 9 = 10(a+1) + (b-1)$ (I still get goosebumps.... sort of....) it's a pretty trivial result if you have *any* capibility of doing *any* algebraic symbol manipulation.  It's practically *impossible* to set up the problem to be proven *without* actually proving it by accident along the way.

Comment: This is ..... a "the proof is too small to fit in the margin" situation.

Answer (score 0):

First, we difine what one means by "n-th multiple of $9$". This will be defined as the number resulting from the n-th natural number multiplied by $9$. In other words, by definition, the n-th multiple of $9$ will be $9\cdot n$.
So, what we are trying to prove is 
$$10(n-1)+10-n=9n$$
(wich btw can easily be shown to be true through simple algebra)

By induction:

$\text{(1)}$
$$10(1-1)+10-1=9\cdot 1 \;\;\; \text{It´s true for $n=1$}$$

$\text{(2)}$

We assume the property to be true for $k=n$

$$10(k-1)+10-k=9k$$
$$10(k-1)+10-k+9=9k+9$$
$$10k-10+10-k-1+10=9(k+1)$$
$$10k+10-(k+1)=9(k+1)$$
$$10\big((k+1)-1\big)+10-(k+1)=9(k+1)$$
If it´s true for $n=k$, it´s true for $n=k+1$

$\square$

Comment: This is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $T_n=10(n−1)+10−n=10n-10+10-n=9n$, which makes our proof way easier, as it is obvious to see that $9 | 9n$. We can still prove it by induction using the base $T_n$ formula.

Let's check if that holds for $n=0$: $T_0= 10\cdot(0-1)+10-0=-10+10=0$, which is true.

Now proceed to the induction step: we have to assume that the $T_n$ formula holds for $k\leq n$ and show that it holds for $n+1$.
$$
\begin{split}
T_{n+1} &= 10((n+1)−1)+10−(n+1)\\
&= 10n+10-10+10-n-1=\\
&= 9n+9 = \\
&= T_n+9
\end{split}
$$
We assumed that $T_n$ is $n$-th multiple of $9$, thus $T_{n+1}$ is also multiple of $9$, which ends the proof. 
$\blacksquare$